# reactJS - send data from one route to another

Tags: reactjs, react-router

my router is as below:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={MainContainer}>
        <Route path="search" component={SearchResult} />
        <Route path="detail" component={Detail} />
    </Route>
</Router>, app)
```

logic, in search result page, there will a bunch of result items. When click one of the item, it will take user to detail page.

I want some data from search result carried over to detail page, without using query string. How would you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like something that you should keep in state instead. Something like `selectedCustomer` or `activeCustomer` maybe?

I'm not sure if you should be "passing" anything from anywhere in the React universe. Feels like the "React" way to do it is top down. Everything should get what it needs from state, not any other component.

What happens if someone lands on your details page from a bookmarked URL? Nothing will have ever been passed to your details page and things will break.

Comment: reason for pass data like this, is because I want to get query url from search page and pass it to one of the bread crumb in detail page.

Comment: Is your `SearchResult` component adding the query param? Maybe it can/should also save it to state?

Comment: let say it be can save to search result's state, how can I access it in Detail component?

Comment: Are you using anything to manage your app state? The purely React way would be to move any state that multiple components need to know about to a level above both of them and then pass it down as props. The probably better way would be to use something like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) to manage your entire app state in one global store and `connect` any components that need access.

Comment: I'm using just purely react. I know how to pass props from parent to children or from children to parent. But passing props from router to router... not sure

Comment: According to the [redux docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.md#passing-additional-values-into-route-components) you can now pass props into routes so maybe you can do it there.